# Get URL beginning with

Tags: javascript, regex, url, extract

I try to extract the first URL beginning with `http://damonpyn.com`. The format of the URL is `http://damonpyn.com/yyyy-mm-ddfb` (only `yyyy-mm-dd` changes with a date).

Here is my example :

```
var str = '...text before http://damonpyn.com/yyyy-mm-ddfb text after...';
var value = str.match(REGEX???);
output = [{urlpyn: value}];
```

Desired result: `http://damonpyn.com/yyyy-mm-ddfb`.

Comment: random things like : /^http://damonpyn.*$/. But not mention it because I have 0 knowledge about regex... (I tried all what I've found on stackoverflow without success..)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = '...text before http://damonpyn.com/2017-01-01fb text after...';
var value = str.match(/http:\/\/damonpyn\.com\/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}fb/)[0];
var output = [{urlpyn: value}];

console.log(output);

// Output:
// [ { urlpyn: 'http://damonpyn.com/2017-01-01fb' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be `/http:\/\/damonpyn\.com\/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}fb/`

There is no `f` and `b` in date function, only uppercase

```js
var str = '...text before http://damonpyn.com/2015-01-01fb text after...';

console.log(str.match(/http:\/\/damonpyn\.com\/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}fb/));
```

Comment: You should probably escape the `.` just in case.

Comment: Also, I thought JavaScript didn't let you choose a different delimiter for your a regular expression? Can you share how this gets used in actual code?

Comment: yes, fb=facebook. It's a tracking link ;) thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: Got it. I was hoping I had just missed a way to use different delimiters. :-)